# How can I store a function with parameters as a variable without calling it immediately?

Tags: python, function, variables

I am creating a translator for my Raspberry Pi that will get an input, then output the Morse code with an LED.

I have a function that will accurately output the Morse code for the letter of my choosing. I am trying to assign the function with parameters to a variable for quicker access like this:

```
a = letter(dot, dash)
```

but when I try and store it like that it runs the function with those parameters, I also can't call it with something like `a()`.

Comment: `a = letter`; `a(dot, dash)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Store function in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945467/python-store-function-in-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called currying, binding arguments to functions returning new functions. Or partial application. Which is the solution to your problem:

```
from functools import partial 
a = partial(func, arg1, arg2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [**`partial`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) for this:

```
from functools import partial

a = partial(letter, dot, dash)
```

Partial constructs a new function. If that function is called, it will call `letter` with `dot` and `dash`. In case you call `a` with parameters, those parameters are added at the end (the *unnamed parameters*), and the named parameters are updated.

Comment: Technically, `partial` does not create a new function. This comes into play when trying to partially apply keyword arguments: `def f(x, y): return x + y; g = partial(f, x=3)`, now `g(5)` will fail instead of returning 8.

Comment: @mkrieger1: it's not really clear why that proofs that `partial` does not create a new function: this simple implementation of partial https://gist.github.com/KommuSoft/14de8731807a44e4cb5e82233952fa45 will create a new function (a scoped `g`) that will raise the same exception as partial. I do not see much difference in behavior.

Comment: Okay, that's right, it's not a proof. I think what I meant was: In order to get an object `g` with that behaviour you cannot use `partial`, but have do define a new function explicitly. And in any case, the type of the thing returned by `partial` is `partial`, which is not a subclass of `type(f)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a variable to a function and then use the variable as the function's name. Here is an example:

```
def cube(number):    
    return number ** 3

make_cube = cube    # Take out those parentheses
```

Now, the variable `make_cube` can be used as a function, like so:

```
print(make_cube(2))
# 8
```

Both `cube` and `make_cube` point to the same memory address, which you can confirm with `id(make_cube) == id(cube)`.

In your case, it can be:

```
a = letter
a(dot, dash)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write the function expression as string and later on call using eval.

```
a = "letter(dot, dash)"
eval(a)
```

(Does not require importing of module)